# Surface of a sphere and cube

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have a sphere $S^2 \in \mathbb{R}^3$ with radius 1 that is painted red on the surface (90% of it), the rest is painted blue.
Now I shall show for every configuration of a  cube that is possible in this sphere, there is always at least one configuration such that a cube with length 2 down each diagonal(that means all corners touch the sphere) has all corners on red painted points.

My idea was the following:

If this was wrong than at each position of the cube there would be a point that is painted blue. Since we have 8 corners, the minimum likelihood for blue would necessarily be 12.5%, such that this fails, right?

But somehow I think my argument is not very strong, as this is one that refers to a discrete configuration. But here we are talking about anuncountable number of points. maybe anybody here knows how to make my argument more rigorous, if it is not even wrong after all?

If something is still unclear, please let me know.

Comment: You have the corners of the cube touching the sphere, not the edges.

Comment: I think you mean there must be a cube with "all four vertices are at red points" rather than all edges. It's the vertices which touch the sphere, each at one point.

Comment: @coffeemath you mean eight vertices

Comment: Correct.  Please edit to say "corners".  Also the statement "Now I shall show for every cube that is in this sphere, there is always at least one configuration such that a cube ..." is really confusing to me.

Comment: Well, that was a half-edit :-) ... there still appears "edges" where it should be "corners" (in your paranthetical remark)

Comment: not anymmore....;-)

Comment: You should try to clean up the problem statement. It's very unclear.

Comment: A possible wording: Given a 90% red 10% blue coloring of the sphere, there exists an inscribed cube with all red vertices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We compute the expected value of red vertices on the inscribed cube. If this number is greater than $7$, we have solved the problem: there must exist some cube with $8$ red vertices.

The probability a vertex is red is $.9$. There are $8$ vertices on a cube and expectation is linear, so there is an expected value of $7.2$ vertices. By the above remark, we're done.

Comment: Note that this is a slightly unusual example of the so-called _Erdős probabilistic method_ (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_method) for proving existence of an object.

Comment: Where are the physical constraints on the cube? The locations of the vertices aren't independent.

Comment: @John Expectation is linear even when the variables aren't independent.

Comment: I notice that this coincides with my answer, but John's does not. Is there anybody who could point out, which one is correct?

Comment: @Potato I think your answer is fine. If John comes up with a good explanation, why his answer is better, then we'll see, but so far, I think your answer is the right one.

Comment: It appears like you're treating the vertices as being able to move around independent of one another.  They can't do that.  A cube is rigid.  Or am I totally missing the definition of "sphere" and "cube"?  By "sphere" I think "round ball" and "cube" I think "box composed of six squares."  Is that not how it's meant to be defined?

Comment: @John I'm considering them fixed in the shape of a rigid cube, but you're right that this proof works for any rigid configuration of $8$ points that can be inscribed in a sphere. Here's the formalism: Label the vertices $1$ through $8$, and let $X_i$ be a random variable that is $1$ if the $i$th vertex is on a red point and $0$ if it is on a blue point. Then compute the expectation over all inscribed cubes: $E(X_1+\dots+X_8)=E(X_1)+\cdots+E(X_8)>7$.

Comment: @John You are completely right that the $X_i$ are not independent. However, expectation is linear even for dependent variables. This is a handy fact!

Comment: I agree with all who are saying that 21% is only the minimum that can be obtained via John's argument.  I also think 12.5% is the actual cutoff.  Just consider that every point on the sphere is the corner of a unique inscribed cube.

Comment: The cutoff is 12.5%  I thought about it too simply.  Reference:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/499854/problem-regarding-the-fitting-cube-into-sphere