# Unit sphere coloring - Prove that there exists an inscribed cube with only red vertices

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

> Suppose the points of the unit sphere $S^2$ are colored in such a way, that $90\%$ of the surface is **red** and $10\%$ is **blue**. Prove that there exists an inscribed cube with its vertices on $S^2$, such that all of its vertices are **red**.

I think this is a really neat problem. However, I failed to come up with a formal solution. Yesterday our TA provided the solution to the problem. Unfortunately, while I understand it intuitively to some degree I can't make it $100\%$ formal. Here's the solution:

Let $\Omega = \{\textrm{all Cubes in $S^2$}\}$ and suppose $\mathbb{P}$ is the uniform distribution. We define $X_i(\omega) = 1$, if vertex $i$ of $w$ is **red** and $X_i(\omega) = 0$ otherwise. Then $\sum_{i=1}^{8} X_i(\omega) = \textrm{Number of red vertices of $\omega$}$. Now we have $E(X_i) = \frac{9}{10}\cdot1 + \frac{1}{10}\cdot 0 = \frac{9}{10}$ and thus $E(X) = E(\sum_{i=0}^{8}  X_i) = \sum_{i=0}^{8}  E(X_i) = 8\cdot\frac{9}{10} = 7.2 \implies \exists \omega \textrm{, such that } \sum_{i=1}^{8} X_i(\omega) = 8$.

My questions:

> 1. It seems natural that $E(X_i) = \frac{9}{10}$, but how do we arrive at this result and why is it a sum? Since $\Omega$ is uncountably infinite the expected value should be an integral of some kind, but $X_i$ isn't even continuous!
> 2. If we think of the expected value $E(X)$ as some kind of "average" it stands to reason, that there exists a cube $\omega'$ with $8$ **red** vertices. But I'm dissatisfied with this kind of argument. What is the formal background here?

Comment: I just found this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/573926/surface-of-a-sphere-and-cube?rq=1. For 2) it's apparently enough to say that if $E(X) > 7$ there must exist a cube with 8 red vertices (since the number of red vertices must be an integer). But 1) is still unanswered.

Comment: I am not very sure with your doubts. The $X_i$ is an indicator, and marginally, you just choose a vertex uniformly over the whole sphere surface, such that it has a probability of $\frac {9} {10}$ being red. You do not need to consider the joint distribution of all vertex locations; just consider you are choosing a point to fix the "first" vertex inside the sphere.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, BGM. I think I'm starting to understand what you mean; I guess each time I'm selecting a point on $S^2$ as the first vertex I also select a unique cube (that is 7 other vertices). Then again $X_i$ takes elements of $\Omega$ to the set $\{0,1\}$. Which version of expected value applies to this random variable? None of the cases listed at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Definition seems to apply.

Comment: If you accept the fact that $\mathbb{P}\{X_i = 1\} = \frac {9} {10}$, then the answer you posted follows trivially as you are just calculating the expectation of an indicator, which is just equal to this probability. I am not sure if I can help if you have some doubts for this probability. Maybe you consider $\omega = (\omega_1, \ldots, \omega_8)$ which contains all the coordinates of the vertices, and actually you are just marginally picking one of the $\omega_i$ for consideration. Actually $\omega_i$ provide all the necessary information as the argument of $X_i$

Comment: Thanks again, BGM. Up until now I haven't thought about the relationship of random variables and indicator functions. In this case we're dealing with the indicator function of the set of red points and this set of course has measure $\frac{9}{10}$.